# .deb package shows a different dependency when the system has already been updated

Tags: python, debian-squeeze, dependencies

I want to install emesene2 on Debian Squeeze, but it shows some dependency problemes like Python, which needs >=2.6.6-7 and python-papyon0.5.

I installed Python 2.7 and used update-alternatives to use Python 2.7 intead of 2.6. When I test `python --version` I got Python 2.7.2+, but when I run `dpkg -i python-papyon_0.5.5-2_all.deb` I am told that the system is still using Python 2.6.

```
 python-papyon depends on python (>= 2.6.6-7~); however:
 Version of python on system is 2.6.6-3+squeeze6.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid taking any action to change system-wide default Python version. Rather wait until the distro changes to that version, and you won't have to do anything other than keeping your system updated. If you want to use a specific version, simply call it directly, e.g.:

```
python2.7 script.py
```

Here's one other guy who [got into trouble](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9711/) for trying to change the default.

> How can I solve this issue?

Your issue is a little different from the warning above. It's a dependency issue that should have been fixed by using APT. Why are you using dpkg? Your system is also not up-to-date. You would not have received this error if it was. Since you are running Squeeze, do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```